# Any way to get more details about "internal failure" errors reading gmail from googleapi?

Tags: google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I've run into a lot of cases where google's api yields a less-than-descriptive error message.

Now I'm getting this:

```
Google_Service_Exception Object
(
    [errors:protected] =>
    [message:protected] => {
 "error": "internal_failure",
 "error_description": "Backend Error"
}
```

I'm reading batches of 100 messages at a time with the php googleapi client listUsersMessages function call.

Interestingly, I notice that if I ask for a batch that's not a round mod 100 number, I get a result list rounded to 100. For example I ask for a batch size of 156 (just to test) and I get 100. That's just a side note.
The real problem is everything works fine, until I get to some large number, like 8500, or 15000, and then I get the internal_failure error.

One thing I did notice, is that the exception object I get back from the php client is fantastically huge. Printed to my log file, it's 272162 lines long. There's a lot of repetition. There's many iterations of 85 array entries that look like this...

```
 [sorted:GuzzleHttp\Event\Emitter:private] => Array
      (
        [before] => Array
          (
             [0] => Array
                (
                  [0] => GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Prepare Object
                      (
                      )
                  [1] => onBefore
                )
             [1] => Array
... this goes up  to 85 and then repeats all over again.
```

I'm thinking there's some object that needs to be reset somewhere because something is leaking in the api and after 85 calls, something on the google end blows up.

Am I missing some cleanup function call somewhere?

Comment: The Gmail API has a [quota](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota) of `250 units/second per user`. This can be exceeded for short burst, but not for long. Maybe this is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'll give that a go, although I don't think my program is that fast. Thanks.

Comment: nope, I added a 1 second sleep between each fetch of 100 and it still gave me "error": "internal_failure"

Comment: Shoot. Then I have no idea :( Hopefully a pro can chime in.

Comment: I actually ran the google sample php get message list code and it does the same thing so it blew up as well. I think it's a capacity thing. It's leaking something, and at some point, game over.

Comment: That's odd. Have you tried something more extreme, like 5s between each fetch maybe?

Comment: I'll try it, but it won't be very useful if I can only read 100 mails every 5 second. :-)

Comment: Still happens. It takes a lot longer, but it will eventually come back with internal failure.